# How to share a view between formats with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails controller which provides both HTML and PDF responses, and thus I have `view.pdf.haml` and `view.html.haml` files. These are either identical or *extremely* close to identical.

How can I have Rails use a single view for multiple formats?

Comment: This is what we used to have, but once you add Turbo into the mix it insists on views including a format. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify what format to render with `:formats` option:

```rb
# Both will render view.html.haml

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :view }
  format.pdf  { render :view, formats: :html }
end
```

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-formats-option*

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean have the same action serve up different resource types - i.e. both a web page and a PDF? If I understand the problem, you can use the [`respond_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) method.

```
def show
  @object = Object.find params[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf { ..code to render the pdf.. }
  end
end
```

That `..code to render the pdf..` is the tricky part. There are PDF gems that support inline rendering, but you may end up using `send_data` or similar to set a file name, disposition, etc and deliver the PDF document to the end user.

Comment: No sorry, everything works currently, but I have duplicate views—one for the PDF and one for the HTML. I want format.html and format.pdf to both use the same one

Comment: Oh, you are just trying to eliminate the duplication between the two files? It's hard to know without seeing them, but can the common code be moved to partials / helper methods?